# Is there any packages in flutter for augmented/virtual reality (AR/VR)?

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality

Hi everyone,
I need augmented/virtual reality (AR/VR) packages in a flutter. I have tried many packages all the packages are in the deprecated version... Give me a package that supports flutter now.

I used this version,
arcore_flutter_plugin: ^0.0.2+2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vd42w.png)
I need a solution to this,
Currently, this package is not supporting what should I do about it.

Comment: https://github.com/CariusLars/ar_flutter_plugin

Comment: This is not working